# PL/SQL procedure successfully completed but no output in Oracle SQL developer

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

When running the code snippet in Run window of the SQL developer it works fine and out is shown in the OutputVaribles section at the bottom. But when running the procedure from the SQL file it is getting completed successfully but no output is shown

```
set serveroutput on

DECLARE
INTCHARTIDS DDI.P_CHARTS_QUERY.ARRAYINTCHARTIDS;

A DDI.P_CHARTS_QUERY.CURSOROBJECT;
B DDI.P_CHARTS_QUERY.CURSOROBJECT;
C DDI.P_CHARTS_QUERY.CURSOROBJECT;
D DDI.P_CHARTS_QUERY.CURSOROBJECT;
E DDI.P_CHARTS_QUERY.CURSOROBJECT;
F DDI.P_CHARTS_QUERY.CURSOROBJECT;
G DDI.P_CHARTS_QUERY.CURSOROBJECT;
H DDI.P_CHARTS_QUERY.CURSOROBJECT;
I DDI.P_CHARTS_QUERY.CURSOROBJECT;

BEGIN
   INTCHARTIDS(1):=2568;
   DDI.P_CHARTS_QUERY.OPENCHARTS(INTCHARTIDS=>INTCHARTIDS,
                         INTUNITSYSTEMID=>30,
                         INTEDITEDBY=>1565,
                         INTOPENMODE=>1,
                         CHARTOBJECT=>A,
                         CHARTAXISOBJECT=>B,
                         CHARTSERIESOBJECT=>C,
                         CHARTSERIESRUNOBJECT=>D,
                        CHARTSUBSETOBJECT=>E,
                         CHARTSUBSETDATAOBJECT=>F,
                         CHARTANNOTATIONOBJECT=>G,
                         CHARTSERIESCONTROLRUNOBJECT=>H,
                         CHARTSERIESRUNGROUPOBJECT=>I
                         );

END;
```

[**PL/SQL procedure successfully completed, but no output**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gtg37.jpg)

Comment: What output are you expecting? The code you've shown doesn't produce any. Does the procedure you are calling have `dbms_output` calls? Or are you expecting to see the contents of your local `cursorobject` variables?

Comment: I was missing the forward slash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer to this.

I had tried multiple options but now got to know that I need to put in the forward slash **(/)** at the end of procedure. Then can assign the output to the cursor variables.

```
    set serveroutput on;

VAR CHARTOBJECT refcursor;
VAR CHARTAXISOBJECT refcursor;
VAR CHARTSERIESOBJECT refcursor;
VAR CHARTSERIESRUNOBJECT refcursor;
VAR CHARTSUBSETOBJECT refcursor;
VAR CHARTSUBSETDATAOBJECT refcursor;
VAR CHARTANNOTATIONOBJECT refcursor;
VAR CHARTSERIESCONTROLRUNOBJECT refcursor;
VAR CHARTSERIESRUNGROUPOBJECT refcursor;


DECLARE
INTCHARTIDS DDI.P_CHARTS_QUERY.ARRAYINTCHARTIDS;

A DDI.P_CHARTS_QUERY.CURSOROBJECT;
B DDI.P_CHARTS_QUERY.CURSOROBJECT;
C DDI.P_CHARTS_QUERY.CURSOROBJECT;
D DDI.P_CHARTS_QUERY.CURSOROBJECT;
E DDI.P_CHARTS_QUERY.CURSOROBJECT;
F DDI.P_CHARTS_QUERY.CURSOROBJECT;
G DDI.P_CHARTS_QUERY.CURSOROBJECT;
H DDI.P_CHARTS_QUERY.CURSOROBJECT;
I DDI.P_CHARTS_QUERY.CURSOROBJECT;

BEGIN
   INTCHARTIDS(1):=2619;
--   INTCHARTIDS(2):=2572;
--   INTCHARTIDS(3):=2573;
   DDI.P_CHARTS_QUERY.OPENCHARTS(INTCHARTIDS=>INTCHARTIDS,
                         INTUNITSYSTEMID=>30,
                         INTEDITEDBY=>1565,
                         INTOPENMODE=>1,
                         CHARTOBJECT=>:CHARTOBJECT,
                         CHARTAXISOBJECT=>:CHARTAXISOBJECT,
                         CHARTSERIESOBJECT=>:CHARTSERIESOBJECT,
                         CHARTSERIESRUNOBJECT=>:CHARTSERIESRUNOBJECT,
                        CHARTSUBSETOBJECT=>:CHARTSUBSETOBJECT,
                         CHARTSUBSETDATAOBJECT=> :CHARTSUBSETDATAOBJECT,
                         CHARTANNOTATIONOBJECT=>:CHARTANNOTATIONOBJECT,
                         CHARTSERIESCONTROLRUNOBJECT=>:CHARTSERIESCONTROLRUNOBJECT,
                         CHARTSERIESRUNGROUPOBJECT=>:CHARTSERIESRUNGROUPOBJECT
                         );

END;
/
Print CHARTOBJECT  ;
Print CHARTAXISOBJECT  ;
Print CHARTSERIESOBJECT  ;
Print CHARTSERIESRUNOBJECT  ;
Print CHARTSUBSETOBJECT  ;
Print CHARTSUBSETDATAOBJECT  ;
Print CHARTANNOTATIONOBJECT  ;
Print CHARTSERIESCONTROLRUNOBJECT  ;
Print CHARTSERIESRUNGROUPOBJECT  ;
```